# elasticsearch exporter how to correctly pass login/password through ES_USERNAME/ES_PASSWORD

Tags: elasticsearch

Could you please help me with the following issue? I set up elasticsearch exporter (https://github.com/prometheus-community/elasticsearch_exporter), elasticsearch cluster has authentication configured, so I pass ES_USERNAME and ES_PASSWORD environment variables in request URI when launching exporter: `./elasticsearch_exporter --es.uri=https://$ES_USERNAME:$ES_PASSWORD@myhost:9200`, but at startup I get an authentication error 401. At the same time, if I directly pass the login/password to the request URI `./elasticsearch_exporter --es.uri=https://myuser:mypassword@myhost:9200`, then everything works correctly, but this method is insecure and login/password are displayed in the output of ps aux and systemctl status. How to correctly pass these variables? The output echo $ES_USERNAME and echo $ES_PASSWORD displays the correct value